# Can actionBar give title spatial priority over actions?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-optionsmenu

In an Android app, we have an option menu item called "Contact", which we'd prefer to be shown as an action in the action bar (instead of hidden under the three-dot menu). So we use

```
menuItem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
```

However when we do that, the "CONTACT" action takes away room from the activity's title. So the title gets cut off with ellipses:

[image: Action bar with title cut off]

Instead, we'd like the title string to take priority over "IF_ROOM" actions for space in the action bar. In other words, if there's not room to show both the title string and the "CONTACT" action, hide the "CONTACT" action under the three-dot option menu.

Is there a way to do this?

P.S. I realize there are other ways to save space in this action bar image, e.g. removing the "up arrow," shrinking some margin, etc. That may be helpful, but this question is not about other ways to save space.

Answer (score 0):

**in your menu add  android:showAsAction="never"**

```
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <!-- menu -->
        <item android:id="@+id/contact_id"
              android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_contact"
              android:title="@string/action_contact_id"
              android:showAsAction="never" />

        <!-- menu -->
    </menu>
```

**Or in code**

```
MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. This solution will make sure that `CONTACT` is **never** shown in the ActionBar, right? I want it to show *if there is room without cutting off the title*.